# Can .net core 5.0 API start a winform UI applicaiton

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, interop

Is it possible to have a .net core 5.0 API start a Winform UI?  If so how? In VS it works when I use kestrel; but in IIS the winform process is running without the UI being visible.  I need to run the  winform tester application on local windows 10 workstation.  The tester application is to fire off when it receives a web request message. Have had seemlier issue attempting to accomplish the objective with a window service.  Process runs, but no UI.  Any advise would be appreciated...

Comment: I think for this to work you need to make sure the IIS process runs under the same user account than the currently logged in user.

Comment: A web server that runs a winforms UI on the server sounds... pretty unusual; would it not be better to have a separate UI admin console (in any technology you like) that talks to the web-server via http, sockets, or something like that?

Comment: I set the iis application pool identity to my domain user id.  Getting 503 Service unavailable.   Tried local system getting same result as applicationpoolidentity. process runs, but no ui.

Comment: Do you mean create a console application that would have to always be running in the background.  Kind of like a windows service, but since the console application doesn't run on process 0, so it can interact with the UI processes.  The user should not be able to kill the console application and console should not be visible to them.  It would listening for web request messages, and would fire up the tester application..